# Java Exception: Array indexes out of bounds

Tags: java, algorithm

I was given a lab assignment where we were asked to fill an array of size 50. The first 25 elements had random distinct elements, and the remaining have to be each 26 . All we have to do is print the repeating element,which obviously is 26, using the Las Vegas Algorithm .

I wrote the program and since it's my first time at Java , I am stuck with an exception of Array indexes out of bounds.

I am also sure that there is nothing wrong with the algorithm, and please note that I first created a list and then converted it to array of Integer type.

Hoping for a helping hand.

The code is as follows :-

```
public class NewClass {
    static Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    public static void lasveg(Integer a[],int n)
    {
        int i,j;
        boolean chk= true;
        while(chk)
        {
            i=(randomGenerator.nextInt())%n+1;
            j=(randomGenerator.nextInt())%n+1;
            if((i!=j)&&(a[i].equals(a[j])))
            System.out.println("The repeated element is : " + i);
        }   
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {        
        int i ;
        Integer[] arr = new Integer[50] ; //used the Integer wrapper class instead of primitive int
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList(50);
        for (i=1; i<26; i++) 
        {
            list.add(i) ;
        } 
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        for(i=26 ; i<51 ; i++)
        {
            list.add(26) ;
        }      
        list.toArray(arr) ;
        for(i=0 ; i<50 ; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " "); 
        }
        lasveg(arr,50);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Please show your exception stack trace. 2) Please indicate which line throws it via a comment in your code.

Comment: 3) Choose a specific title

Comment: 4) Please read [ask]

Comment: In addition to the solutions people are giving you, you don't really need the '%' operation if you use the following java API method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)

Comment: @halloei Fixed the title

Comment: Thanks halloei and ThatGuyRussell . I am quite new to StackOverflow , and would adapt to the laws and conventions soon !

Answer (score 2):

The code has several issues:

1. randomGenerator.nextInt() could return negative numbers and you
   can't use negative numbers as index for an array.
2. if you use % n+1 then you could get an index bigger than 49, which
   should be the highest index in an array of length 50.
3. the third thing is that you have a endless loop, because you never
   end the while(true)

If you change all that then your code could look like that:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class NewClass {
    static Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    public static void lasveg(Integer a[], int n) {
        int i, j;
        boolean chk = true;
        while (chk) {
            i = Math.abs(randomGenerator.nextInt()) % n ;
            j = Math.abs(randomGenerator.nextInt()) % n ;
            if ((i != j) && (a[i].equals(a[j]))){
                System.out.println("The repeated element is : " + i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        Integer[] arr = new Integer[50]; // used the Integer wrapper class
                                            // instead of primitive int
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList(50);
        for (i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        for (i = 26; i < 51; i++) {
            list.add(26);
        }
        list.toArray(arr);
        for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        lasveg(arr, 50);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
24 20 19 14 13 16 10 7 22 18 12 15 2 6 3 25 17 8 1 21 4 5 11 23 9 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 The repeated element is : 26
```

Comment: Thank you sir, they were some terrible mistakes. I am glad I was made to figure them out.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

If you call this function with n = 50 and your array a got 50 elements

```
    public static void lasveg(Integer a[],int n)
        {
            int i,j;
            boolean chk= true;
            while(chk)
            {
                i=(randomGenerator.nextInt())%n+1;
                j=(randomGenerator.nextInt())%n+1;
                if((i!=j)&&(a[i].equals(a[j])))
                System.out.println("The repeated element is : " + i);
            }   
    }
```

Whats happen there is if the random number is (50*x)-1 % 50 + 1 you calling a[50] thats throwing an out of range exception. 
You aint want to increase the term ***rand % n*** then you get a range from 0 to 49.

Answer (score 1):

Your `i` and `j` variables are assigned a random number in the segment from 0 to `n`, including `n`

```
i=(randomGenerator.nextInt())%n+1;
j=(randomGenerator.nextInt())%n+1;
```

In Java the index of the last element of array of `n` elements is `n-1`, so there is a possibility, that this statement

```
if((i!=j)&&(a[i].equals(a[j])))
System.out.println("The repeated element is : " + i);
```

will cause the index out of bound exception.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you have here it's that you have to notice that **arrays starts at position 0**.

```
array[0];
```

So, when you use your method `lasveg` you are setting the number `50` and really trying to access to the position `51` where you do `a[i]` and `a[j]` here:

```
if((i!=j)&&(a[i].equals(a[j])))
```

To fix your problem you will have to do:

```
lasveg(arr,49);
```

---

Another solution it's to avoid the `+ 1` in your `Random`. Change this:

```
i=(randomGenerator.nextInt())%n+1;
j=(randomGenerator.nextInt())%n+1;
```

to this:

```
i=(randomGenerator.nextInt())%n;
j=(randomGenerator.nextInt())%n;
```

I expect it will be helpful for you!